# How manually write/edit XSD file to generate DataSet class without using the designer

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xsd, dataset, designer

In the past (< Visual Studio 2017) I've always just written/edited the DataSet's XSD file directly in my Visual Studio projects to then automatically have VS generate the Classes for the strongly typed DataSet for me.

In the XSD I could manually set the default value, the nillable attribute, etc.

For some reason recently in VS 2017 I can't do that anymore. When I use the DataSet visual designer to e.g. set the AllowDbNull attribute of a table field to 'false'; the resulting c# classes work as expected but this field info does NOT get written to the XSD file anymore (e.g. there is no nillable or msdata:AllowDbNull attribute for that field element). The only 'traditional' attributes for the field that show up are: type and default. Manually adding the attributes to the element in the XSD file also doesn't work; the DataSet designer ignores these - one can only set them and have them work properly using the designer.

That pops the question of where VS actually stores the table field information like AllowDbNull; it seems the VS DataSet designer keeps some kind of config file somewhere where this info is kept - it's not in the XSD anymore like it used to be.

The only thing visible in the XSD for a table named 'test' with a field named 'label' with AllowDbNull = false set in the designer is this:

```
<xs:element name="test" msprop:Generator_TableClassName="testDataTable" msprop:Generator_TableVarName="tabletest" msprop:Generator_TablePropName="test" msprop:Generator_RowDeletingName="testRowDeleting" msprop:Generator_RowChangingName="testRowChanging" msprop:Generator_RowEvHandlerName="testRowChangeEventHandler" msprop:Generator_RowDeletedName="testRowDeleted" msprop:Generator_UserTableName="test" msprop:Generator_RowChangedName="testRowChanged" msprop:Generator_RowEvArgName="testRowChangeEvent" msprop:Generator_RowClassName="testRow">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="label" msprop:Generator_ColumnVarNameInTable="columnlabel" msprop:Generator_ColumnPropNameInRow="label" msprop:Generator_ColumnPropNameInTable="labelColumn" msprop:Generator_UserColumnName="label" type="xs:string" default="bla" />
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```